# UI performance monitoring tools

Tags: javascript, performance, logging, user-interface, monitoring

I am looking for a tool that lets you monitor/log page rendering time on **client machines**. I am not looking for firebug/yslow because i want to know the following type of things:

- How does fast do my pages load when the user is in russia?
- How long does it take for javascript to run on some pages for everyone who accesses those pages?

So, i actually care what my site *feels like* to the people who use it. Do there exist tools that already do this?

I should add that my website is a software as a service website, **not accessible publicly**.

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of any way to do this. One solution, which may be terrible, might be to log the time yourself. At the top of your page have an inline script tag with a global variable called start that creates a new date. Then, have an onload listener that calls a function once the page is finished loading. In this function, get the difference between the start time and current time and send that back to your server. This is by no means that accurate, but might give you some idea. You could also log their IP address for geolocation when you send back the  data.

Comment: This is accurate to ~15ms, except of course it doesn't include the time between when the user clicked on the link to go to your page and when it loaded the first line of inline JS. You could use cookies to track this time for user navigations between pages on your site. HTML5 Web Timing will make this easier: http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/WebTiming/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend https://www.atatus.com/. Atatus helps you to visualise page load time across pages, browsers and countries. It also has AJAX monitoring and Transaction monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a super easy way to do this effectively. but you can definitely fake the geo-location thing by using a proxy (which would actually give you N*2, time length) and get a pretty good idea at what it's like to browse your site.

As for JavaScript, you can profile it with the profiler in FireBug, this will give you an idea of what functions you should refactor and whatnot.

In my opinion I'd determine what most of your users are using or what the general demographic makeup they are, are they 75 year-old guys? If that is the case maybe they aren't up on the newer faster browsers, or for that matter don't care. If they are cool hipster designers in San Francisco, they its Safari 4.0... anyway this is just a way to determine the meat of the users, I think the best way is just grab an older laptop with Windows XP on it and just browse your site, you can use [FireBug lite](http://getfirebug.com/) on browsers besides Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I like to run [Dynatrace AJAX edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/) from UI automation tests. This easily allows you to monitor performance deterioration and improvement over time. [There's an article on how to do this on the Dynatrace website](http://blog.dynatrace.com/2010/05/21/how-to-use-your-selenium-tests-for-automated-javascriptajax-performance-analysis/).